# androidでタイトルバーを非表示にしたい

Tags: android

androidでアプリ開発をしている時にタイトルバーを消したいのですが、

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

をしてもエラーを吐いてしまいます。

ご教授お願いします．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

多分それはAppCompatの問題があります

`AndroidManifest.xml`を編集して下さい：

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

そして、`res/values/styles.xml`には：

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```